# Real Time Analytics: Which database?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, scalability, olap

We are currently using MongoDB, and it is performing well for our needs. However, we are looking to support better real-time analytics and aggregations, which MongoDB doesn't handle effectively. Therefore, we are exploring other possibilities.

The biggest problem is my data is so much flexible. We store:

- contacts
- events

Every contact has different attributes. For example, besides standard attributes such as first_name, last_name, email, phone, gender, etc. there could be additional/custom attributes that users can create.

Also, we have events such as order, add to cart, the coupon applied, etc. Every user can push different events -- like in Google Analytics, for example.

We want to support the following queries:

- Select all users from London
- Select all users from London who created between 3 and 5 orders whose minimum value is $100, in the last 90 days.
- Select all users from Germany who purchased T-Shirt in the last X days

and so on...

Currently, we don't have such aggregations (count, average, etc).

As you can see, our data is quite unstructured. We are exploring several options to improve this, including MongoDB + Spark, ClickHouse, MariaDB ColumnStore, Apache Druid, Apache Pinot, and others.

Since different attributes have input types, we could create two tables:

**contacts**

- workspace_id
- attribute_string_1
- attribute_string_2
- attribute_string_3
- ...
- attribute_integer_1
- attribute_integer_2
- attribute_integer_3
  ...
- created_at
- updated_at

and have a few hundreds of such columns.

The same is for **events**:

- workspace_id
- event
- event_attribute_string_1
- event_attribute_string_2
- event_attribute_string_3
  ..
- event_attribute_integer_1
- event_attribute_integer_2
- event_attribute_integer_3
  ..

etc.

This means every column can be used in the WHERE clause for filtering... plus we need to join them (or use dictionaries in ClickHouse, for example). Currently, we have a nested array in MongoDB for easier handling.

Questions:

1. What do you think might be the best choice for such a problem?
2. How to organize indexes to support such dynamical data?
3. What about time series databases?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Since different attributes have input types, we could create two tables...attribute_string_1, attribute_string_2, attribute_string_3
>
> 1. What do you think might be the best choice for such a problem?

Well that would defeat the purpose of using a NoSQL database like MongoDB, and you could just use a regular RDBMS at that point. But the type of queries you described that you want to run are pretty typical for an RDBMS, and it sounds like you have a pretty standard schema outside of the user customizable stuff.

Also, some RDBMS have both traditional row level storage (for OLTP queries) and columnar storage (for analytical/ OLAP queries), such as PostgreSQL which I believe has columnar storage extensions, and Microsoft SQL Server which has columnstore indexes.

> 2. How to organize indexes to support such dynamical data?

That'll very much depend on how you design the schema to hold the user customizable data. With the pre-defined generic column model, you can designate certain columns to be the index keys and pre-index them, and then force the end user to map which data point is their key field from a group of data points.

Alternatively, your application can ask the end user to designate one or more fields as the key fields, and then the application generates the appropriate SQL script to create that index accordingly.

> 3. What about time series databases?

You don't really have time series type of data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wouldn't create fields like `attribute_string_1` if I decide to stay with MongoDB. In that case, I'd use MongoDB for storing unstructured data and also use Apache Spark for for real-time analytics. They have a native integration" https://www.mongodb.com/products/spark-connector